# Self-made SQL model vs. ORM?

Tags: web-applications, orm, refactoring, lamp

I've read Stack Overflow discussion about ORM advantages and drawbacks, and there are different opinions. I would like to describe this particular case.

- LAMP based medium scaled web application with some spaghetti code inside.
- The code is quite far from being OOP, though there are controllers with embedded templates, and weak model classes branch.
- There are several dozen MySQL tables, and about thousand files.
- Caching, tuned for performance MySQL queries with indicies.
- About a million views per month.
- Users have mostly read access.

My question is this:

**Is it worthwhile to implement an ORM (Doctrine2 or Propel), or should I limit myself to writing model classes from the scratch** (similar to ActiveRecord pattern, group methods/queries by table and record, so each entity has two related classes)?

The primary aims are:

1. application performance,
2. ease of code/queries readability and modification, and
3. ease of possible DB (details) modification.

Personally I prefer the second choice; there are quite complex SQL queries, I doubt an ORM would be able to maintain DB abstraction for all queries. The initial development is over and there is no need for rapid speed of development of code/query code. It is much more important for us to be able to read, understand and modify code/queries easy.

On the another hand, there could be some strong points in ORM use for given conditions that I miss.

Answer (score 1):

Structuring your code will definitely help you with 2 and 3 and if done right, 1 shouldn’t suffer either. As you incorporate third party ORMs, good performance should be easier to achieve since these ORM support features like caching and lazy loading “out of the box”.

I’d suggest you try to refactor your application in small steps, simultaneously with adding new features or resolving bugs thus avoiding huge refactoring projects that are difficult to justify and manage.

I’d say that a good way towards using third party ORM is to organize your existing code and queries in similar manner. So, you might introduce ProductRepository class that has the method find() encapsulating existing query and returns a ResultSet. Next, you should introduce Product Data Class (class with only fields and no methods). Product class should map the Product table in the DB. Now find should return array of Products. The find() method will now convert a ResultSet to array of Products first and return the array. Client code should be modified accordingly. Finally, you start replacing your custom queries inside find() method with delegation to ORM. Clients using Repository should not detect the change. The Product data class is a seed of your model layer. As you go on, you can add behavior to it and create a real domain layer.

Going back to your question, I’d say you first group your existing code in a form of custom Active Record (I suggest Repository, but in the end it’s just the question of organization) and then you introduce ORM. So, it’s not either-or situation, but first and second stage in refactoring.

I would approach this in the following way:

1. Write some automated tests first
2. Try to separate code in different layers: presentation, domain, persistence.
3. Perform refactoring as described in previous section.

Implementing fully fledged, reusable ORM is a lot of work, so I’d suggest you incorporate existing one and start introducing it in small steps.

I have described this approach in quite a detail in my Professional Refactoring in C# book and you can download the sample code that will lead you through [here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Refactoring-in-C-ASP-NET.productCd-047043452X,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html).